# Fastapi uploaded file not saved

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-upload, zip, fastapi

I am a beginner in fastapi. I am trying to save a zip file uploaded from the front end

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
import os
import zipfile
import shutil
app = FastAPI() 


@app.post('/FileUpload/')
def FileUpload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    dest=os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath(__file__))) +f'\FILES\{file.filename}'   
    if zipfile.is_zipfile(file.file):   
        try:            
            with open(dest, "wb+") as file_object:
                shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, file_object)
        finally:
            file.file.close()
    else:
        print("Invalid File type")
    return {"Status": True}
```

Currently, only a 1KB file of the same file name is saved in the folder, not the uploading file.
Am I missing something here or any issues in this approach?

Appreciate your help and Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The unescaped backslash might be a problem

Comment: This doesn't look particularly complete...? See [example]

Comment: @user202729: I tried escaping the backslash but remains the same. Also updated the code as reproducible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it's not a problem in this case, I would hihghly suggest using [`pathlib.Path()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) to define the destination for your upload

The issue seems to be related to [`zipfile.is_zipfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.is_zipfile). Even though the documentation doesn't specify this, the function apparently "scans" the whole file and leaves the stream at the end (not sure whether this is a bug or a feature). At the same time, the `shutil.copyfileobj()` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) tell us:

> [...] Note that if the current file position of the *fsrc* object is not 0, only the contents from the current file position to the end of the file will be copied.

To better understand what's going on, you can add a [`.tell()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.tell) at various positions in the code.

To fix the issue, you can use [`.seek(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) to reset the stream position:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
import zipfile
import shutil

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/FileUpload/')
def FileUpload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    dest = Path(__file__).resolve().parents[1] / "FILES" / file.filename
#          ^^^^
#          Not directly related to your problem but more elegant imho.

    print(file.file.tell())
    # 0  <- stream position is at the beginning

    if zipfile.is_zipfile(file.file):   
        print(file.file.tell())
        # <file size in bytes>  <- stream position is at the end

        # Reset the file stream:
        file.file.seek(0)

        print(file.file.tell())
        # 0  <- stream position is back at the beginning

        try:
            with open(dest, "wb+") as file_object:
                shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, file_object)
        finally:
            file.file.close()
    else:
        print("Invalid File type")

    return {"Status": True}
```